# Which Xcode version supports Mac 10.10.5?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a **10.10.5** version Mac and I would like to know which version of **Xcode** supports this version? (I am not planing on upgrading)

Answer (score 0):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) say OS X 10.10 supports Xcode version 6.x, 7.2.1.

Comment: 7.2.1 is the latest in that table.

Comment: @GSerg are you sure? In English wiki it's 7.x but in Russian specified 7.0, and as i remember i had to update to El Capitan to use new Xcode.

Comment: I am sure the "min OS X to run" column in [that table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-_7.x_.28since_Swift_2.0_support.29) contains `10.10.5` for XCode v7.2.1, and `10.11` for XCode v7.3. Whether that is correct, I have no idea.