# Xcode version for Mac OS10.10.5

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

What Xcode version should I download for Mac OSx Yosemite (10.10.5)? The latest version that is there on Appstore says that it is not compatible with my version of OS?

Comment: You really need to update macOS. The version of Xcode that you can use with Yosemite is far too old to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) and this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577384/which-xcode-version-supports-mac-10-10-5) say OS X 10.10 supports Xcode version 6.x, 7.2.1.